# Mock HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem in xunit test

Tags: moq, xunit, .net-4.5.2

I have a method using 
`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` which I wish to unit test some behaviour before this call, however, the test is failing with `System.InvalidOperationException : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

I suspect this I need to mock the HostingEnvironment but unaware of how to.

Answer (score 42):

To resolve this issue I defined an interface

```cs
public interface ITaskScheduler
{
    void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Action<CancellationToken> workItem);
}
```

In production code I inject implementation

```cs
public class AspNetTaskScheduler : ITaskScheduler
{
    public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Action<CancellationToken> workItem)
    {            
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(workItem);
    }
}
```

In test code I inject implementation

```cs
public class TaskScheduler : ITaskScheduler
{
    public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Action<CancellationToken> workItem)
    {
        workItem.Invoke(new CancellationToken());
    }
}
```

I think this is an OK solution since unit tests work and my classes that queue background tasks are decoupled from `HostingEnvironment`.

Comment: This is how it should be decoupled! Should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 7):

I ended up doing this to keep things simple:

```
/// <summary>
/// add some jobs to the background queue
/// </summary>
public static class BackgroundTaskScheduler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// send the work item to the background queue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="workItem">work item to enqueue</param>
    public static void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Action<CancellationToken> workItem)
    {
        try
        {
            HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(workItem);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            workItem.Invoke(new CancellationToken());
        }
    }
}
```

Then to fire a job simply:

```
BackgroundTaskScheduler.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
{
     // bla
});
```

Answer (score 7):

A little bit neater than calling `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` regardless of whether there's an ASP.NET AppDomain then catching the `InvalidOperationException` is:

```
public static void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Action<CancellationToken> workItem)
{
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
    {
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(workItem);
    }
    else
    {
        workItem.Invoke(new CancellationToken());
    }
}
```